# Background service modifying new tab page, manifest V3, - what permissions needed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to make a chrome extension which overrides the new tab page and then a background service makes changes to that page. So in my manifest I have (among other things):

```
  "manifest_version": 3,
      "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "newtab.html"
      },
  "permissions": [  "scripting", "activeTab" ... and many many others!
```

This works fine in as much as when I add a new tab I indeed see the contents of the file I put in my own custom "newtab.html".

In the manifest I also put...

```
"host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "chrome://newtab/"
],
```

...then in my background service, just as a test, I put:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tabId },
    func: () => {
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.textContent = 'Hello';
    document.body.appendChild(h1);}
  });
```

But when this code runs I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://mhjkkbnnfoaeadgpnoheabgocjfhgkli/newtab.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

I have searched widely for answers and have added many different permissions and host_permissions but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't allow executeScript on extension's own pages, but there's no need for it anyway.

1. Remove `permissions`, `host_permissions`, and `background` from manifest.json.
2. Add `<script src=newtab.js></script>` at the end of your html
3. Use the standard JS and DOM methods inside newtab.js

Comment: Oh my god... my search for the correct permission could have been a long one! Thank you.